# time complexity method-call calculation

Tags: java, time-complexity

when calculating the time complexity of a method call, do I have to consider the complexity of the method too or just consider the complexity as constant time?
thanks thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to consider the complexity of the method.

Here is a simple example that illustrates the point: imagine you have an algorithm that sums all the elements of a matrix; you can do :

```
sum = 0
for (i = 0; i < m.M; ++i)
    for (j = 0; j < m.N; ++j)
        sum += m[i, j];
```

or :

```
sum = 0
for (i = 0; i < m.M; ++i)
    sum += sumRow(m, i);
```

with sumRow:

```
for (j = 0; j < m.N; ++j)
    sum += m[i, j];
return sum
```

As you see you can't consider the sumRow function as having a constant complexity because its execution time depends on the dimensions of the problem.

But if the method does not depend on any dimension you consider it as executing in constant time.

As an example you could project the values before summing:

```
sum = 0
for (i = 0; i < m.M; ++i)
    for (j = 0; j < m.N; ++j)
        sum += project(m[i, j]);
```

Then you consider project as constant time because it only depends on a scalar value not the dimensions of the matrix.

Comment: What do you mean: if you are in the first case with "sum += m[i, j];"? Whatever the approach the complexity of the algorithm is NxM. Methods are just a way of tructuring the algorithm but they won't change its complexity which is one of its intrinsic properties.